# Normalizing self referencing attributes

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, normalization

What is the best way to normalize information about a `spouse` in a database containing information about `persons`?

The data includes:

```
person_id
first name
middle name
last name
phone number
address
vehicle
house
health
destiny
items
spouse first name
spouse middle name
spouse last name
spouse phone number
spouse address
```

I was thinking of keeping a single table to regard all `persons` (spouse or otherwise) and to distinguish a `spouse` if its row has a value for the `person_id` of another `person`. Is this sort of self reference advisable?

I was also going to create tables for repeating data. Such as `health`, `vehicle`, etc.

Comment: I don't see the `lead_id` column to which you refer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalizing spousal information would include removing the `spouse *` columns. If you want a self-referencing table, you should have a `spouse_id` column that references `person_id`; but don't repeat all the spousal information like name, address, and phone number.

For one-to-many relationships like person-to-vehicle, yes, you will want tables on the "many" end (e.g. `vehicle`) with a `person_id` FK column.

Also, strongly consider breaking `address` out to its own table.  If you are planning to store all the elements of an address in this one column, that is very denormalized (< [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)): they should be broken out into distinct columns (e.g. `street`, `municipality`, `region` etcetera); and these really beg to be in a distinct table.

Are self-referencing tables advisable?  It really depends on the situation; but they make sense where they come up naturally in data in my experience: I think a generic "person" scenario as you have outlined it qualifies.  In contrast, consider a rather contrived "picture" scenario - table `picture` containing a `of_picture_id` column to cover pictures of pictures...of pictures....  (Hmmm, now that doesn't sound so contrived to me...; but hopefully you get the idea.)

Answer (score 3):

Spouse is also a "person", hence the spouse's details has to be captured as a separate record. The only way that can be done is by introducing `spouse_id` as a self referential key. The above table you have shown is not normalized since a person's table contains another person's details. I suggest you modify the 'persons' schema the following way

```
 person_id
 first_name
 middle_name
 last_name
 phone_number
 address
 vehicle
 house
 health
 destiny
 items
 spouse_id
```

Comment: It's not normalized (to 3NF at least) for several reasons, some others of which I have outlined.  Dropping `spouse *` and adding `spouse_id` was clear nearly half an hour ago. :)  The question also  asks about the advisability of such self-referencing relationships as the one in which `spouse_id` would be involved.

Comment: Right. I've already upvoted your answer @J0e3gan. My point was to make it clear to the OP what the modified table should look like :)

Comment: Clarity has value, and I grant that the list of columns is clearer - with respect to `spouse *` and `spouse_id` at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
PARTY
id
name

PARTY_RELATIONSHIP
from_party_id not null references party(id)
to_party_id not null references party(id)
from_date not null
to_date null
primary key (from_party_id, to_party_id, from_date)
check (from_party_id <> to_party_id)
```